# Oracle 10G XE on RHEL 5.3

Tags: oracle, rhel, ora-01031

I installed Oracle 10G XE on RHEL 5.3 . I am able to login as user oracle to the database, but am unable to do so as root.

If i try to login as root using 'sys as sysdba' username i get `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`
The root user is part of the dba group. Any way to fix this ?

Thank You

**edit**

Additional info:

When logged in as root if i go to 127.0.0.1:8080/apex, I get Insufficient Privileges message when i try to login. But tryin to login to RHEL as user oracle, gives me the following message ...

`GConf error:Failed to contact configuration server;some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP for ORBit,or your have NFS locks due to a system crash.(Details-/:IOR file'/tmp/gcofd-cheetahman/tock/ior' not opened successfully,no gconfd located:Permission denied`

... and gnome does not load properly

(APC copied these details from in-thread comment)

Comment: It is bad practice to have root as a member of the dba group, or indeed to use root for the kind of tasks which require connecting to Oracle. That's why Nature gave us `su` and `sudo``.

Comment: Agree with comment, but if you till now needs reasonable answer, please provide more details about your installation.

Comment: Try removing `gconfd-oracle` and `orbit-oracle` folders from `/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

This would seem to be a problem with your installation.  For instance, a chap posted to a linux forum in 2004 with a scenario which is spookily similar to yours.  The bad news is he didn't seem to get a resolution but [check it out anyway](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gnome-not-working-correctly-412947/).

Under the circumstances you might get better responses on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) or a dedicated  RHEL/Linux forum.